# jquery executes before html is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make the html load before javascript function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 10;
    if(x == 10) {
        $('h1').text("Its changed !");
        alert("Test");
    }
})
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Here the alert message will popup,

I also tried,

```js
$(function(){
    window.on('load',function(){
        //code
    })
})
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the expected output

Comment: did you import the jQuery library?

Comment: by default html is loaded before javascript

Answer (score 0):

The basic method to do what you want is to add the scripts at the end of html code at the end of body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet should only be :

```
window.onload = function(){
    /*some code*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that javascript does not wait for .text() to finish before continuing.  Alert then fires, which freezes the browser, preventing text() from completing.  There are a couple of ways around this.  You could avoid calling functions that freeze the browser (like alert()) or set a timeout before calling alert, like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert('Test')},20);
```

The timeout will allow time for the previous execution to finish before calling the code within the function.

Comment: You don't need to wait 200. You can probably just do setTimeout(function(){alert('Test')});

Comment: I copied the code into a fiddle, and you need at least about 20ms before it consistently updates the text before the alert appears.  I'm updating my answer.  You are right that 200 is much longer than necessary.